# How can set a ViewController to have Extend Edges Under Top Bar programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In Storyboard I have option to put viewController content under top bar! How can I do that programmatically?

What I want(I think) is `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.Top` but doesn't work...

Answer (score 11):

Put this code in your viewController's `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = [.top]
```

Comment: Or in obj-c: self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

Comment: I use that "edgesForExtendedLayout = .None" to remove option "Under Top Bar", but I want to put this option, not to remove.

Comment: @Cosmin replace .none with .top then

Comment: .none is not available anymore in Swift 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315841/how-to-set-edgesforextendedlayout-to-none-in-swift-3

Answer (score 1):

If you mean navigationBar, use `yourNavigationBar.translucent = YES;`

Answer (score 1):

```
controller.edgesForExtendedLayout = [.top]
```

Comment: use this in viewDidLoad (I prefer)