# How to set edgesForExtendedLayout to none in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

The problem is that my View, containing a `UIView` and a `UITableView` within a `ScrollView`, gets hidden under the `UINavigationBar` **if set translucent**.

I have considered several threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824994/view-got-hidden-below-uinavigationbar-ios-7), but they all suggest to set:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone
```

In Swift 2, this code was:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None
```

I have updated to Xcode 8.1 and Swift 3.0.1 today, but I can't find anything in the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html) about this matter.

The compiler tells me, that `.None` got changed to `.none`, but after edit, that `.none` does not exist. Changing it to `.top` did not had any effect.

The tableView is setup programatically and putting `insets` does not help because I have a `scrollView` with a `UIView` on top of the `UITableView` that is hidden under the `UINavigationBar`.

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Set it to `[]`. That is the same as none.

Comment: i even need to wait 10 minutes now before i can accept your answer. that did not happen since a while

question: is `[]` always the same as `.none` or just in that case?

i wasn't able to find anything

Comment: Yes, `[]` is the same as `.none` as matt indicates.

Answer (score 15):

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .init(rawValue: 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

SWIFT 5 solution

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)

   self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but I just added the following code in my `viewDidLoad()` and it solves my problem.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: forcing a different navigationbar style does not solve this problem AT ALL